# WebRTC mutli broadcasters multi viewers and single video recording with recordRTC

Tags: javascript, php, video, webrtc, recordrtc

I am trying to create a web event where, multiple broadcasters live streams and viewers watches them live. The broadcaster will have their turn, which gets selected by the event host. So basically there are three user types in an event (1) one event host(is also a broadcaster), (2) multiple broadcasters(event speakers) and (3) multiple viewers.

And record event streaming from start to end with host and speaker camera. Note that host video and audio will record throughout the event. If video not possible then at least audio.

I successfully integrated this library: https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection

With this library I am able to show camera of host and multiple broadcasters of event and viewers able to watch them live without camera.

For recording, I am using RecordRTC to record every video of event speaker(starts recording once turn starts and stop recording once turn ends) and upload it to the server, and then after finishing of each speaker's turn I am merging all recorded videos using ffmpeg.

But, I want to remove ffmpeg merging and want to record full event with host video and selected event speaker video one after another as single recorded video.

For that, I stored all video/webm blob in a file and **want to merge all video/webm blobs to create a single video file** but found no solution.

I also **tried using webpage canvas recording solution but it is not recording video element.**

Canvas recording demo: https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/Canvas-Recording/webpage-recording.html

Can anybody help me with either recording of all webm blobs as single video file or using canvas to record streaming videos as single recording?

Comment: You can use this library to pass single stream over RecordRTC ( https://github.com/muaz-khan/MultiStreamsMixer ). It will record all videos in single file. RecordRTC also has documentation here: https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC#record-multiple-videos

Comment: @MuazKhan Thank you for your comment. I tried record-multiple-videos of RecordRTC from the link, one video recording is working fine but it gives me error when I tried to call addStreams method("addStreams is not a function") of RecordRTC instance. I will have only one stream recording at the start and need to add stream of the user when his turn starts . So adding new stream to the active recording is crucial. And can I remove any specific stream once user turn ends?

Comment: You can use "getInternalRecorder" method to access internal recorder which has "addStreams" and "resetVideoStreams" methods. The internal recorder is actually this object: http://recordrtc.org/MultiStreamRecorder.html

Comment: @MuazKhan Thanks again. So you are saying, I should use MultiStreamRecorder instead of RecordRTC to add streams, right? I tried using MultiStreamRecorder instance(RecordRTC.js) and used record and stop methods but its giving me error "arrayOfMediaStreams.forEach is not a function" on RecordRTC.js:5305. Can you please help me with some basic working demo of recording and stream adding on the fly?

Comment: @MuazKhan Can you please reply, is it possible to add streams in the active recording on the fly? Or is it possible to merge two video blobs?